# bonsai tree identification

Tags: identification, indoors, bonsai

Please can someone help me identify this bonsai! It looks like rosemary or buddhists pine but its neither of those.[image]

Comment: I think it is *Podocarpus* (Buddhist Pine), what makes you think it is not?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this is a podocarpus macrophyllus (Buddhist Pine). But it seems to be lacking water.

Answer (score 0):

Podocarpus tree this is only guess as I'm new to this

Comment: Welcome, it would be nice to have unique answers instead of repeating whats been said before.  You could make it unique by posting an image that makes you sure about the identity